# Getting a DateTime value using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am pretty new to Linq so this simple problem made me stuck: All I want is to take datetime value from query:

```
  var queryW = (from r in aTable.AsEnumerable()
                    where r.Field<string>("Department") == "Workshop"
                    select r.Field<DateTime>("LastCall"));
```

and convert it from `var` to `datetime`

```
  DateTime AliveW = Convert.ToDateTime(queryW);
```

which leads to exception:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.DateTime]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

I've tried as well

```
  DateTime AliveW = Convert.ToDateTime(queryW.FirstOrDefault<DateTime>);
   DateTime AliveW = Convert.ToDateTime(queryW.First<DateTime>);
```

without luck

Comment: `queryW` is a _collection_ of `DateTime` objects. Pick one of the items in that collection, not covert the collection. The `First()` might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query as you have it will return an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` i.e. a *collection* of `DateTime`s that can be enumerated/iterated over, but you are trying to get only one `DateTime`. Did you want only the first i.e.

```
var queryW = (from r in aTable.AsEnumerable()
                where r.Field<string>("Department") == "Workshop"
                select r.Field<DateTime>("LastCall")).First();
```

Note that this will throw an exception if there are no `DateTime` in the collection, in which case you may want to use `FirstOrDefault()`, which will return `default(DateTime)` in the case where the *collection* does not contain any `DateTime`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your linq query does not return a single value like you think.  The error is telling you that you are getting an enumerable of the row collection type.  If you know for sure that your query should return one value you could add a .Single() or .First() call to the end of your query.

Comment: Thanks for information, I was trying to use .Firstordefault<> but I was using it wrong. Guess thats why question was downrated :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryW = (from r in aTable.AsEnumerable()
            where r.Field<string>("Department") == "Workshop"
            select r.Field<DateTime>("LastCall")).FirstorDefault();
```

**Try to use var instead of DateTime**

```
var AliveW = Convert.ToDateTime(queryW);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to it

```
 DateTime usTime = (DateTime)(aTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>r.Name=="Reporter").Select(r => r.UsTime).First());
```

Try this, Mark it as a answer if it works